# Does the cost to repair items with mending enchantment go up?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Does repairing your item using the mending enchantment make it use more xp as you repair it? Also does how many times you repaired it in the anvil affect how much xp is required to repair?

Comment: Wait, there is a mending enchantment in vannila minecraft?! Are you sure you are not using mods?

Comment: @Gamer3001 Mending is a new enchantment as of Minecraft Snapshot 15w42a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now(1.9 Snapshot 15w44b), repairing an item using the mending enchantment, does not increase anvil costs. Mending repairs items at a rate of 2 durability per experience point, regardless of how many times you have repaired it at the anvil.

That, of course, is subject to change, since 1.9 is not officially released yet, but it will probably work this way.